# Dart: How to convert variable identifier names to strings only for variables of a certain type

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Using Dart here.

As the above title suggests,  I have a class (shown below) that has three bool instance variables. What I want to do is create a function that inspects the identifier names of these instance variables and prints each of them out in a string. The .declarations getter that comes with the ClassMirror class ALMOST does this, except it also gives me the name of the Constructor and any other methods I have in the class. This is no good. So really what I want is a way to filter by type (i.e., only give me the boolean identifiers as strings.) Any way to do this?

```dart
class BooleanHolder {

  bool isMarried = false;
  bool isBoard2 = false;
  bool isBoard3 = false; 

 List<bool> boolCollection; 

  BooleanHolder() {


  }

   void boolsToStrings() {

     ClassMirror cm = reflectClass(BooleanHolder);
     Map<Symbol, DeclarationMirror> map = cm.declarations;
     for (DeclarationMirror dm in map.values) {


      print(MirrorSystem.getName(dm.simpleName));

    }

  }

}
```

OUTPUT IS: 
isMarried
isBoard2
isBoard3
boolsToStrings
BooleanHolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code.

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

void main() {
  var type = reflectType(Foo);
  var found = filter(type, [reflectType(bool), reflectType(int)]);
  for(var element in found) {
    var name = MirrorSystem.getName(element.simpleName);
    print(name);
  }
}

List<VariableMirror> filter(TypeMirror owner, List<TypeMirror> types) {
  var result = new List<VariableMirror>();
  if (owner is ClassMirror) {
    for (var declaration in owner.declarations.values) {
      if (declaration is VariableMirror) {
        var declaredType = declaration.type;
        for (var type in types) {
          if (declaredType.isSubtypeOf(type)) {
            result.add(declaration);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

class Foo {
  bool bool1 = true;
  bool bool2;
  int int1;
  int int2;
  String string1;
  String string2;
}
```

Output:

```
bool1
bool2
int1
int2
```